# Python: Simple If-Else statement not working

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm coding a dynamic programming function that finds the longest substring that's a palindrome in Python:

```
def longestPalindrome(s: str) -> str:
        dict = {}
        start = 0
        end = 0

        # initialize base cases and left of base cases
        for i in range(len(s)):
            dict[(i,i)] = 1

        for y in range(len(s), -1, -1):
            for x in range(y, len(s)):
                print((x,y))
                # memo check
                if (x, y) not in dict.keys():
                    if s[x] == s[y]:
                        if x - y == 1:
                            dict[(x,y)] = 1
                            if (end - start) <= (x-y):
                                start = y
                                end = x

                        elif dict[(x-1,y+1)] == 1: # if substr betweet x & y is palindrome
                            dict[(x,y)] = 1
                            if (end - start) <= (x-y):
                                start = y
                                end = x                        
                    else:      # ISSUE HERE
                        dict[(x,y)] = 0

        return s[start:end+1]
```

I get the following error when inputting "aaabaa" into the function:
**KeyError: (4, 1)**

When I make the following changes, it outputs correctly

```
def longestPalindrome(s: str) -> str:
        dict = {}
        start = 0
        end = 0

        # initialize base cases and left of base cases
        for i in range(len(s)):
            dict[(i,i)] = 1

        for y in range(len(s), -1, -1):
            for x in range(y, len(s)):
                print((x,y))
                # memo check
                if (x, y) not in dict.keys():
                    dict[(x,y)] = 0  # **CHANGE**
                    if s[x] == s[y]:
                        if x - y == 1:
                            dict[(x,y)] = 1
                            if (end - start) <= (x-y):
                                start = y
                                end = x

                        elif dict[(x-1,y+1)] == 1: # if substr betweet x & y is palindrome
                            dict[(x,y)] = 1
                            if (end - start) <= (x-y):
                                start = y
                                end = x                        
#                     else:         # **REMOVE**
#                         dict[(x,y)] = 0

        return s[start:end+1]
```

I'm pretty sure the two versions of the functions are logically the same, but I cannot figure out why the first doesn't work.

Comment: along with that error, you also get a backtrace that's telling you which line the error happened on.  There's a lot of places where dict[tuple] is used so it's not obvious which it is.  Make a habit of including the full error message to maximize quality of responses.

Comment: strongly recommend against a variable named `dict` as `dict` is a builtin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to place the `else` one tab width back? Your `else` ought to be matching with the memoization step. It is matching with `if s[x] == s[y]:`

Comment: the concern that makes me want to say, don't put so many python blocks inside each other because python makes it really confusing where one ends and another begins.  Use functions to encapsulate blocks of code to alleviate this challenge.